# Proving that Ν(θ,1) is the only location-parameter family with mean θ and variance 1 and with an MVB Unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let Y be an RV with location-parameter density $ f(y|θ)=h(y-θ) $ where h is a pdf on R associated with mean 0 and variance 1.We have

$$I_f* (θ) = Ε(\{\partial_θf*(y|θ)\}^2)= E_0(\{\frac{h'(Y)}{h(Y)}\}^2)=:I(Y) $$

I(Y) being independent of θ and  $Ε_0$  referring to the $ θ=0 $ situation.Consider also

$$ J(Y):= E_0(\{\frac{h'(Y)}{h(Y)}-\frac{φ'(Y)}{φ(Y)}\}^2)=I(Y)-1 $$ where φ is the pdf of $N(0,1)$.Suppose that we have shown that if $J(Y)=0$ then $Y$~$N(0,1)$(then I guess $f$ must be ~$N(θ,1)$).Since $J(Y)\ge0$ it is clear that $I(Y)\ge1$.Show that this is the Cramer-Rao MVB for the location parameter situation and that $θ\to N(θ,1)$ is the only location -parameter family with mean θ and variance 1 and with an MVB Unbiased estimator.

My thoughts: suppose $T(Y)$ is an unbiased estimator of θ then $Var(T|Y)\ge\frac{1}{I_\ell(θ)}=\frac{1}{I(Y)}$ .  $I_\ell(θ)=nI_f* (θ)$ being the fisher information and in our case n=1.Τreating θ as a random variable Θ with pdf $π(θ|y)$ then  $π(θ|y)$ has the same pdf as f(y|θ) since its proportional to the likelihood and in our case n=1 and likelihood is f(y|θ).Now for $N(θ,1)$ the mean is an MVB unbiased estimator and its variance is 1.Since I(Y) is independent of θ then the Cramer-Rao MVB result must be $Var(T|Y)\ge1$ for all $π(θ|y)$ pdfs and in extend for all f(y|θ)=h(y-θ) location-parameter densities(h a pdf on R with mean 0 and variance 1).So if there is a an MVB unbiased estimator then the estimator's variance equals 1 and $J(Y)=0$ showing that $f$~$N(θ,1)$ and $θ\to N(θ,1)$.

(Assume that we cant use Rao–Blackwell and Lehmann–Scheffé theorems.